# how to check if an object with a certain date already exists in a ArrayList

Tags: java, object, arraylist, compare, localdate

I'm kinda stuck in a project im doing. So I'm writing a Hotel class (parent) and a Reservation class (child).

In my reservation class im creating new reservations to be made at the Hotel. My Reservation Constructor is taking the following arguments `Reservation(String name, String Email, int phonenum, LocalDate fromDate, LocalDate toDate).`

However, I now want to check if a reservation is already made when creating a new reservation.
All my objects is kept in an `ArrayList`, but I'm not really sure how to go about this, given the way I've constructed the dates. Any pinpointers would be much appreciated!

EDIT:

```
            public List<Reservation> addBooking(int addBooking){  // argument doesnt do anything at the moment, havent decided what I should opt for. 
                if (addBooking <= 0 || addBooking > 10)
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Number of reservations must be higher than 0 and can't exceed 10!");
                
                
                else
                    reservations.add(new Reservation("Alex Test", "abrdwa@gmail.com",99323223,LocalDate.now().plusDays(10), LocalDate.now().plusDays(15)));
                    reservations.add(new Reservation("Criss Test2", "acdef@gmail.com",47825433,LocalDate.now().plusDays(10), LocalDate.now().plusDays(15)));
                    reservations.add(new Reservation("Frank Test3", "abcde@gmail.com",41722210,LocalDate.now().plusDays(10), LocalDate.now().plusDays(15)));
                    reservations.add(new Reservation("Elea Test4", "abcd@gmail.com",99321312,LocalDate.now().plusDays(10), LocalDate.now().plusDays(15)));
                    reservations.add(new Reservation("Monica Test5", "abc@hotmail.com",99922223,LocalDate.now().plusDays(10), LocalDate.now().plusDays(15)));
    
    
            
            return reservations;
    
            }
```

Comment: Please paste code into the editor itself rather than putting a link to an image. This way others can read your code much quicker. You can mark it as Java code and it will have proper syntax coloring.

Comment: Also doesn't look like you explain what the `int addBooking` parameter is for and it is not used anywhere.

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of the int addBooking. It doesnt do anything at the moment. I will fix that shortly, once I decide what I want the argument to do.

Comment: Is it a matter of fitting your `Reservation` class with an `equals` method?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a high level approach I would take.

1. `Hotel` class contains ArrayList of `Reservations` but you don't modify it directly..
2. `Hotel` class has an `boolean addReservation(Reservation)` method that takes a `Reservation` and either adds it to the array and returns true or returns false if it's "already made".
3. The term "already made" needs to be defined more clearly. Do you mean the same reservation is already made? Or you mean that you want to check that it doesn't conflict with other reservations? If the latter, then you need to loop through the existing reservations and compare the dates start and end times with each.

Comment: Yes, already made, hence conflicting. My problem is that I dont see how I can compare those dates when my dates are created the way they are. 

Highly appreciate the response and time!

Comment: How is the way you make them effecting it? Can't you just use `LocalDate.compareTo()` or `isBefore` or `isAfter` etc.? See https://howtodoinjava.com/java/date-time/compare-localdates/

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to think about what is the same reservation. All the fields are the same including the exact date? Or overlapping date? Or just the name and email? Depending on this overwrite the equal method in Reservation.
Than you could add a check:

```
if(reservations.contains(newReservationAttempt){
  //do whatever you want, return a boolean inside a method or
  throw new ReservationAlreadyExistException()      
}
```

An other possibility would be to check criteria with Java Streams and any match.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Sorry for being unclear - I only want to check if the to and from-date already exists, you can ignore everything else.

So if there is an reservation already made from 20.02.2021 - 25.02.2021

and you're trying to make a reservation for the exact same periode, it should throw an error.

Making a reservation from 21.02.2021 - 25.02.2021 should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

## `LocalDateRange`

I suggest you add the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your project. This library brings classes that add to the *java.time* functionality built into Java 8 and later. Indeed, both this library and *java.time* are led by the same man, Stephen Colebourne.

In particular, *ThreeTen-Extra* offers the [`LocalDateRange`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html) class. This class represents a span of time as a pair of `LocalDate` objects. The class offers handy methods for comparison, such as `abuts`, `overlaps`, and so on.

So your `Reservation` class should contain a member field of `LocalDateRange` for the start and stop dates.

If using Java 16 or later, we can write your `Reservation` class more briefly as a [record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395). In a record, the compiler implicitly creates the constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`.

```java
package work.basil.example.hotel;

import org.threeten.extra.LocalDateRange;

public record Reservation(String customerName , String customerEmail , int id , LocalDateRange arriveDepart)
{
}
```

Write a method to search a list, examining each `Reservation` record object for its contained `LocalDateRange` object, and ask if it overlaps with our target date range.

```java
    boolean isDateRangeTaken ( List < Reservation > reservationList , LocalDateRange dateRange )
    {
        boolean taken = false;
        for ( Reservation reservation : reservationList )
        {
            if ( reservation.arriveDepart().overlaps( dateRange ) ) { return true; }
        }
        return taken;
    }
```

Exercise that code.

```java
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" ) );
        List < Reservation > reservationList =
                List.of(
                        new Reservation( "Alex Test" , "abrdwa@gmail.com" , 99323223 , LocalDateRange.of( today.plusDays( 10 ) , today.plusDays( 13 ) ) ) ,
                        new Reservation( "Criss Test2" , "acdef@gmail.com" , 47825433 , LocalDateRange.of( today.plusDays( 10 ) , today.plusDays( 15 ) ) ) ,
                        new Reservation( "Frank Test3" , "abcde@gmail.com" , 41722210 , LocalDateRange.of( today.plusDays( 10 ) , today.plusDays( 17 ) ) ) ,
                        new Reservation( "Elea Test4" , "abcd@gmail.com" , 99321312 , LocalDateRange.of( today.plusDays( 10 ) , today.plusDays( 19 ) ) ) ,
                        new Reservation( "Monica Test5" , "abc@hotmail.com" , 99922223 , LocalDateRange.of( today.plusDays( 10 ) , today.plusDays( 19 ) ) )
                );

        LocalDateRange near = LocalDateRange.of( today.plusDays( 11 ) , today.plusDays( 13 ) );
        boolean isNearDateRangeTaken = this.isDateRangeTaken( reservationList , near );
        System.out.println( near + " is taken: " + isNearDateRangeTaken );

        LocalDateRange far = LocalDateRange.of( today.plusDays( 180 ) , today.plusDays( 183 ) );
        boolean isFarDateRangeTaken = this.isDateRangeTaken( reservationList , far );
        System.out.println( far + " is taken: " + isFarDateRangeTaken );
```

When run.

```
2021-02-28/2021-03-02 is taken: true
2021-08-16/2021-08-19 is taken: false
```

We can use streams and lambda syntax to search the list.

```java
        LocalDateRange target = LocalDateRange.of( today.plusDays( 18 ) , today.plusDays( 22 ) );
        List < Reservation > hits =
                reservationList
                        .stream()
                        .filter( reservation -> reservation.arriveDepart().overlaps( target ) )
                        .toList();
        System.out.println( "Overlapping " + target + " is: " + hits );
```

When run we find the last two elements in the list are hits.

```
Overlapping 2021-03-07/2021-03-11 is: [Reservation[customerName=Elea Test4, customerEmail=abcd@gmail.com, id=99321312, arriveDepart=2021-02-27/2021-03-08], Reservation[customerName=Monica Test5, customerEmail=abc@hotmail.com, id=99922223, arriveDepart=2021-02-27/2021-03-08]]
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the process of [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).